# Will this AC-DC converter chip really work with arduino?

Tags: power, current

I am looking for a compact solution to convert some 220V/20amp AC to something edible by our arduinos (like 5V/2amp DC). I would like to plug directly my arduino to the wall. I found many things like some Hi-link ([HLK-PM01](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-1pcs-lot-HLK-PM01-AC-DC-220V-to-5V-mini-power-supply-module-intelligent/32408565688.html)) chips ... But I also found this one :

- [LNK564DN - US $0.34 / piece](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/PN8359-precision-CCCV-PSR-AC-DC-converter-PN8359-DIP-8-One-from-the-sale/32592989301.html)
- [LNK564DN - US $1.14 / piece](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/LNK564DN-AC-DC-converter-switch-off-SMD-package/32518518757.html)

That seems perfect, but unfortunatly, I can not find any tuto or example of use for this, shipping included, really cheap chip.

The datasheet [is here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/328/lnk562-564-6129.pdf).

What do you think about it ?

Comment: " I would like to plug directly my arduino to the wall." - Why? What for?
If you want to power the Arduino you could use one of [these](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12889). If you want to sense 220VAC try [this](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/noninvasive-ac-current-sensor-100a-max-p-547.html).

Comment: Where will you source the transformer from?

Comment: The goal is to create a compact prototype which can be pluged into the 220v (France) wall plug. Don't you think the LNK564DN should do the job to give the prototype the current it needs ? Thanks.

Comment: The LNK564DN is the controller for a power conversion circuit.  To use it, you also need four diodes, four capacitors, three resistors, a special transformer, and a circuit board. You can get an "AC 100-240V 0.3A DC 5V 2A EU Plug USB Power Supply Adapter Charger" on Ebay for $1.74 with free shipping.

Comment: @Charaf What EXACTLY are you plugging into the 220VAC? I mean exactly what pins?

Comment: @James 200VAC plug -> AC-DC converter -> Arduino nano -> HC-06 + ESP8266. I am trying to put all of this in a simple compact case.

Comment: @jwpat7 Thank you ! I thought it was as simple as the hlk-pm01 =)

Comment: So you are powering the nano not sensing the 220VAC. Like @Jake C told you: It's dangerous. We use an off the shelf power supply, or a [wall adapter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12889). That's the best solution but it's over to you whether you take the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do you think about it ?

If you have to ask, don't do it. Mains voltage can be **dangerous** and should only be done if you know what you are doing and how to be safe. The best choice is to just use pre-built adapters from reputable sources.

Comment: It is a good advice. Thank you. But I think I can take the risk, it's for learning purposes =)

Comment: Buying random chips from China and asking on internet forums is not the best way to be learning about how to work with mains voltage.